# A quick way to return all the dates in a table from a database partitioned by DATE and SYMBOL

Tags: database-partitioning, dolphindb, data-partitioning

I have a table in a database partitioned by DATE and SYMBOL, and the DATE column is of the TIMESTAMP type.

Is there any faster way to return all the dates in the table than the statements `select distinct(date(datetime)) from t` and `select count(*) from t group by date(datetime)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**:

Query the date partitions by `schema(db).partitionSchema`. This method is only applicable to the situation where the range of the required dates is not less than the date range specified by the partition scheme.

For example, the partition scheme specifies a database("",VALUE,2020.01.01..2020.01.10) with a ten-day range. If you only append data of one day in a partitioned table within the database with `schema(db).partitionSchema`, the result is still the ten days. If you append data of 2020.01.01~2020.01.15 (fifteen days), you can obtain all the 15 days.

**Method 2**:

The first level of database is partitioned by DATE. You can get the partition metadata by the function `getTabletsMeta`, and then get the results in temporal data types by the function `temporalParse`.

For more instructions of the function, refer to [getTabletsMeta](https://dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/g/getTabletsMeta.html#gettabletsmeta) and [temporalParse](https://dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/t/temporalParse.html?highlight=temporalparse).

For example, there is a database “SH_TSDB_tick” using DATE and HASH partitioning. To get all the dates of table “tick”, you can write the following script:

```
dbName = "dfs://SH_TSDB_tick"
tbName = "tick"
result = exec dfsPath from getTabletsMeta(dbName[5:]+"/%", tbName) where rowNum != 0
dateList = substr(result, regexFind(result, "[0-9]{8}"), 8).distinct().temporalParse("yyyyMMdd").sort()
```